# How do I close or .hide() and element above the target or action element?

Tags: jquery, hide, accordion

My basic setup is using `.slideDown()` and `.hide()` to create an accordion effect. I have a "toggle" div, which is the button or what is clicked to `.slideDown()` the element below it, which is hidden by default, using `$(this).next().slideDown()`;

I am doing this within an if statement: `if($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {Do this};`, which allows me to basically use the same divs over and over, all controlled by a single block of script. These divs are stacked vertically: toggle div > hidden div > toggle div > hidden div and so on.

What I want to do is `.hide()` the div above the clicked "toggle" div, which was previously hidden and has been `.slideDown()`. and is now visible.

I have tried to use `if($(this).closest('.hidden').is(':visible')) {Do this};`, where 'hidden' is the selector for the element in question to target that element and then `.hide()` it with no success.

I have read up on `.closest()`, which is why I tried to use it for this purpose. I have also tried to target the div directly, but with multiple instances of the same div, I need to distinguish which div relative to the div being clicked.

Here is the project I am working on: http://www.jeremiahdesign.com/GD491/weekSix/portfolio/index.html

This is a class project. Anyinsight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note: `.closest` only traverses through ancestors, not siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
 $(this).prev().slideUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've well  understood, you can use the following instruction for get the exact div you want:

```
$(this).prevAll("div.ex-link")
```

this allow you to get the previous link you opened

Comment: @Gabrik--Thanks. This worked, but it created another issue. I am scrolling to the opened div when it is opened. My page still scrolls, but too much.

Comment: @Gabrik--Should I delay the scroll until the previous div is finished closing?

Comment: @Gabrik--Figured it out!! \o.o/. Thanks a bunch for the info. I had to change the target of the scroll. Otherwise, when the new div expands and the previous one collapses, the opened div, which was the original scroll target, disappeared because the above div was removed. Thanks again. Joe

Comment: @Nooby_Jay I wanna help you but I'm not near my pc. I'll take a look at your code and answere you asap.

Comment: @Nooby_Jay  right! Now you have to do the same for the **next divs**. If you open a div and then open the previous one, it will stay opened. you can use **nextAll** instead. Let me know

Comment: @Nooby_Jay, change your code as below, and all your divs (nexts or prevs) will be closed properly. hope you like it
`code`
**$('.toggle').click(function(){
    if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next().delay(400).slideDown('slow')
    } else {
        $(this).next().hide();
    }
    if($(this).prevAll("div.hidden").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).prevAll("div.hidden").slideUp('slow');
    }
    // this is the code for the next divs you have to add
    if($(this).nextAll("div.hidden").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).nextAll("div.hidden").slideUp('slow');
    }
});**
`code`